# Huawei S5600 main OIDs?

Tags: monitoring, snmp, network-monitoring

I'm working with NagiosCore to check the stats of my network's switchs (mainly S5700 (modulars and non-modulars) and S5600). Using SNMP (v2c) I'm able to get stuff defined by myself such as: *DeviceName*, *Location*, *Contact*, and *Description* of the ifaces (ports) I'm currently using, as too the status (up/down) of those mentioned ifaces.

Now I would love to also check **CPU_usage**, **MEM_usage**, **Temperature**, **PowerSupply_Status**, and **Bandwith_usage**. I can do it trough `snmpget` using the OIDs I get from [Huawei Infoweb](https://support.huawei.com/infomweb/topic/index?domain=2&lang=en&type=command) but only for the S5700, I can't find any information in that web (or in any other web) related to the S5600's OIDs, I don't know if the S5600 is discontinued or what, but it is not showing on any of the Huawei Infoweb webs...

[S5600 not showing up in Huawei Infoweb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGmtP.png)

Sooo... I would like to know the S5600's OIDs related to:

- CPU_usage
- MEM_usage
- Temperature
- PowerSupply_Status
- Bandwith_usage

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try OIDs from this template
https://share.zabbix.com/network_devices/huawei/huawei-quidway-s5600-series-switches-template

Comment: Mate, that link doesn't work for me :-(, maybe can work for another producer of the S5600. The only OID I found in that link that maybe work for me it is the *CPU medium load*: `.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.3.3.1.2`, but doesn't start with the right code, when should be: `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.6.1.1.1.2.65536`, starting with the `.1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.`.

Thanks anyways!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker of mine found a chinese blog [ChinaUnix](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=http://blog.chinaunix.net/uid-7411781-id-3376358.html) from where we extract 2 of the OIDs we wanted to use:

**CPUUSAGE**=".1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.6.1.1.1.2.65536"

**MEMUSAGE**=".1.3.6.1.4.1.2011.10.2.6.1.1.1.1.8.20"